# Appending the javascript onclick event to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, phonegap

Im trying to append the onclick event to my Phonegap Application. Where it will link to external browser.

My Code:

```
pair +='<div class="card_background" style="background-image: url("http://placehold.it/600x200");" valign="bottom" class="card-header color-white no-border"><div class="card_overlay"></div><div class="animated_background"></div><h3 class="card-title">'+ results.rows.item(i).title +'</h3></div><div class="card-content"><div class="card-content-inner"><p class="color-gray event_details">Event Location:  <strong>'+ results.rows.item(i).eventlocation +'</strong></p><p class="color-gray event_details">Event Date: <strong>'+ date + " " + month + " " + year +'</strong></p><a href="#" onclick="window.open("'+ results.rows.item(i).eventOrganiserLink +'", _system, location=yes);">Google</a><br/></div></div>';
```

inside loop, 
Later I append it to div

Im trying to add :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open("'+ results.rows.item(i).eventOrganiserLink +'", _system, location=yes);">Google</a>
```

It gives me error

Thanx in advance

Comment: have a look at opening and closing of your quotes: " and '. This `onclick="window.open("...` will close the onclick attribute right after `.open(`. The rest of your code is not ending up in the onclick attribute

Comment: @Meldon How can I solve this Im not getting it. 
please can you rewrite for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code somewhat. Consider the following:

```
var pair = '';
var eventOrganiserLink = '[EVENT ORGANISER LINK]';

pair += '<a href="#" onclick="window.open("'+ eventOrganiserLink +'", _system, location=yes);">Google</a>';
```

This would generate the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open("[EVENT ORGANISER LINK]", _system, location=yes);">Google</a>
```

The `onclick` attribute opens with double quote ("), which means it will look for the first double quote after that to close it. That's right after `window.open(` meaning that part is the only thing that will be set as the onclick attribute. See how the colors in the onclick attribute in the code box here at StackOverflow don't really match up?

It is a little tricky because we're mixing quotes (setting the pair variable) and double quotes (as text inside that variable, which will be used as html later on - so it needs to be valid).

You can use single quotes for the first `window.open` parameter and escape them in the assignment to your `pair` variable, like so:

```
var pair = '';
var eventOrganiserLink = '[EVENT ORGANISER LINK]';

pair += '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\''+ eventOrganiserLink +'\', _system, location=yes);">Google</a>';
```

This would yield:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('[EVENT ORGANISER LINK]', _system, location=yes);">Google</a>
```

Note the single quotes around `[EVENT ORGANISER LINK]`. Also note the colors now match up.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Much appreciated.